# No notable device Acer laptop fresh Ubuntu install

Tags: 14.10

I have an Acer laptop it had windows 10 reinstalled when I bought it.

I have attempted dual boot in the past but no luck and I gave up. Windows 10 had been giving my greif so I decided to use Ubuntu... Now the only OS I have is my bootable Ubuntu flash drive.

I can't boot into Ubuntu at all, it isn't even an option. I am reinstalling Ubuntu now but I thinks there's so other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just reinstalled Ubuntu and it works now. What I did was simply switch to legacy boot before installing. I don't know what the difference is but before legacy didn't change anything but now it seems to, or it was the second install.. Anyway it works now.